# Jquery: How to get the value of an input and put in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

I have an input

```
<input type="text" value="hello" />
```

and I want to get the value of this and using Jquery, save the value in an array.

How can I do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could run this code for submitting:

```
$('formname').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

This would return a string like:

> a=1

You could then save this to an array.

Comment: did I miss something? why are you in a `form`?

Comment: var arr = [];
$('input:text').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});

Comment: ... There are more and more people saying things like "Why are you doing that?" - Does it really matter (providing the answer is correct)?

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var arr = [];
   arr.push($('#inputID').val());
})
```

you should give your input an id

```
<input type="text" value="hello" id="inputID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var formValues = $('#your_form').serialize();
var formValuesAsArray = $('#your_form').serializeArray();
```

To get the value from your input, you should give it a `name` attribute; for example `<input type="text" name="message" />` and get its value by `$('input[name=message]').val()`